# Changing input text language in JS

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to change the text which comes onto the Input.
for example.
if I write in foreign language but a certain attribute is set to True (Angular4, but I want it in typescript) - the input is automatically changed to English without the need of a service that checks the keyCode and changes it.

is it possible within the boundaries of pure JS or typescript or Angular even?

I've already made a service(util) that gets the keyCode from keydown and changes it onto Capital letters but that's a drag and really not smart.

```
uppercase: {
    81: "Q",
    87: "W",
    69: "E",
    82: "R",
    84: "T",
    89: "Y",
    85: "U",
    73: "I",
    79: "O",
    80: "P",
    65: "A",
    83: "S",
    68: "D",
    70: "F",
    71: "G",
    72: "H",
    74: "J",
    75: "K",
    76: "L",
    90: "Z",
    88: "X",
    67: "C",
    86: "V",
    66: "B",
    78: "N",
    77: "M",
    188:",",
    190: "."
  },
```

lets say I have an input, said input is set to Russian.
if i enter a russian letter it'll automatically change to English

Comment: I hope that you are aware of the fact that : just converting characters using `keyPress` events won't be a good practice. You are basically trying to translate languages to ENGLISH, which won't work if you convert char by char. A sentence in Russian can have different numbers of chars than English, plus the grammar will be different. You should reconsider this feature that you are trying to build

Comment: am aware, not trying to translate, but rather just change the keyCode output in an Input.